# Do the encrypt_and_digest() and decrypt_and_verify() methods of the pycryptodome module in python 3 also perform the electronic signature process?

Tags: digital-signature, python

Do the `encrypt_and_digest()` and `decrypt_and_verify()` methods in [pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) also perform the electronic signature process?

I have seen on the internet that the electronic signature consists of signing the message with my private key so that any entity can verify (with my public key) that it was I who sent that file.

But since the `encrypt_and_digest()` method already encrypts the message with my private key and then verifies the integrity of the message with `decrypt_and_verify()`, then the question is raised if they also perform the electronic signature process (authenticity), or if they only do this process to generate the MAC (integrity).

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20_poly1305.html?highlight=encrypt_and_digest#Crypto.Cipher.ChaCha20_Poly1305.ChaCha20Poly1305Cipher.encrypt_and_digest

Comment: "Signing" is ***not*** encrypting a message with a private key, although a lot of people explain it that way. Signing is a specific process and you cannot "sign" something just by encrypting with a private key.

Comment: He was guiding me with this pdf https://readthedocs.org/projects/pycryptodome/downloads/pdf/latest/, I had not seen that page you sent me, I will document the link you sent, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or pdf, where explicitly this is really the signature and electronic certification?